# Как получить номер входящего звонка?

Tags: java, android

Надо получить номер входящего звонка, и при получении номер перейти на следующий activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно в манифесте сделать BroadCast receiver:

```
<receiver android:name=".ServiceReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Добавьте класс который будет обрабатывать входящие звонки и в нем можете прописать переход на след. активити:

```
public class ServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephony.listen(new PhoneStateListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
                System.out.println("incomingNumber : "+incomingNumber);
                // здесь вы можете сделать переход на другое активити

            }
        },PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }
}
```

так же перед тем как перейти на другое активити, вы можете добавить проверку полученного номера на валидность, пустоту строки и тд. Вот [первоисточник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154445/how-to-get-phone-number-from-an-incoming-call). Удачи :)

Comment: Извините но когда я делаю таким способом при звонке  всплывает уведомление с номером телефоном без текста  incomingNumber, так ещё и если удалить весь код из Activity и оставить стандартный который создается при создании Activity то если я позвоню тоже всплывает уведомление с номером